# Why are these tsunami waves so short?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, tsunami

https://youtu.be/wAFYVpX45xs

This apparently shows a coast guard vessel riding the Japan tsunami. But while we are told that tsunami waves haves periods of several minutes, these waves seem to take only seconds to pass. Why is that?

Comment: Looks to me as if the ship rides over the first crest of the wave at around 4:48 in the video, and then it rides over the next crest at 6:50. That's two minutes and ten seconds. The actual period might be a bit longer than that because the ship appears to be motoring into the waves.

Answer (score 1):

"Period" refers to the smallest time interval over which the wave repeats itself.

It looks to me as if the ship in the video rides over the first crest of the wave at around 4:48, and then it rides over the next crest at 6:58. That would indicate a period of around two minutes and ten seconds.

The *actual* period might be a bit longer than that because the ship appears to be motoring into the waves. Probably not a lot longer though, because the wave may be travelling much faster than the ship is able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Water waves (gravity waves) are not traveling in a uniform medium; near a shore, the water depth affects their propogation, and the 'wavelength' is not constant.   Thus, a gentle swell in deep water can become a very high (even cresting and breaking into foam 'whitetops')
wave  of lesser wavelength in shallow waters.

Dispersive wave equations for ocean waves are known, but
those equations do not give rise only to sinewaves.

Comment: Period is constant

Comment: @Abdullah But, period is not wavelength; they are related by speed of propogation of the wave, which is not constant.    The various Fourier components of a water wave also have different speeds, which is a cause of whitewater crests.